# How can I delete an event with CalDAV

Tags: python-3.x, string, http, exception, caldav

I want to delete an Event of my Nextcloud calendar using CalDAV. But when I try to delete an object, I get an error.

This is my code:

```py
import caldav

client = caldav.DAVClient(url='https://ppp.woelkli.com/remote.php/dav', username='XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', password='Xxxxxxxx')
principal = client.Principal()
calendar = principal.calendars()[0]
event = calendar.events()[0]
caldav.Event(client=client, url=str(event), parent = calendar).delete()
```

And in the last line I get the following error: [image]

Comment: You could have used `url=event.url` and it should probably work, but the answer from Alex Watt is more elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the correct code is

```
import caldav

client = caldav.DAVClient(url='https://ppp.woelkli.com/remote.php/dav', username='XXXXXXXX@gmail.com', password='Xxxxxxxx')
principal = client.principal()
calendar = principal.calendars()[0]
event = calendar.events()[0]
event.delete()
```